# How to get a file which is outside the resources path in Java

Tags: java, file, io, classpath

I have this folder strucure

```
backend
|_dispatcher/
|_executor/
|_syncer/
  |_bin/
    |_syncer.bat // To execute the jar
    |_lib/
      |_... // Other dependencies
      |_syncer.jar // Application's jar
|_toolbox-resources/
  |_repositories.json // File to get
```

the **syncer** module wants to get the **repositories.json**. I tried following line to get this file

```
File file = new File(classloader.getResource("../../../../../toolbox-resources/repositories.json").getFile());
```

But this results in a NullPointerException at the end which tells me I failed with this path.

Also I'm not happy with using so many `/../../../` fixtures for the path. Isn't there a way to define some other relational path for the whole application? Or what is the way to achieve what I want to achieve at all?

Comment: Could it be `tool-resources` vs `toolbox-resources`?

Comment: thanks for noticing - but it was only an error in this question

Comment: One last idea: Could it be one `../` too much in your path?

Comment: It definetly is that problem, I already solved it that way. But it's a very hardcoded way in my opinion. I'm looking for convenient ways

Comment: You could use `.ini` files or similiar to define where your resources are. But then you want to have the path to the `.ini` files somewhere. As you see, there's always some limit where you *have* to switch over to hard-coded definition. It's up to you where to set it.